# Why i'm getting error while printing local date time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, localtime

I importing this python modules

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

to_date = date.today()
from_date = to_date - timedelta(days=2)
print(f"Local Date and Time {datetime.datetime.now()}")
```

when I run this code I'm getting error like this_

```
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Can anyone please tell how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO.   You've repeated ```datetime``` in ```datetime.datetime.now()```   You just need ```datetime.now()```

Comment: You have already imported the `datetime` class, so just use `datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import line `from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime` means you imported

- `datetime.datetime` access with `datetime`,
- `datetime.date` access with `date`
- `datetime.timedelta`  with `timedelta`

So as you did for `date` and `timedelta`, `now()` is a method of `datetime` class and not `datetime` package :

```
to_date = date.today()
from_date = to_date - timedelta(days=2)
print(f"Local Date and Time {datetime.now()}")  # not datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put datetime 2 times wrongly. Since you are already importing datetime, it should be like this:

```
print(f"Local Date and Time {datetime.now()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

See the basic example:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
```